# Perfect squares proof.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $z^2=2xy$, with $x,y$ relatively prime, and with only one of them even, then one of them is a square and the other is twice a square.

This is a statement I've found in different proofs without further explanation. Because of that I suppose it should be trivial, but I can't quite see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x=2x'.$ Thus we have that

$$z^2=2^2x'y.$$ Let $x'=p_1^{r_1}\dots p_m^{r_m}$ and $y=q_1^{s_1}\dots q_n^{s_n}$ be their prime factorizations. Since $x'$ and $y$ are coprimes we have that $p_i\ne q_j,\forall i,j.$ Moreover (note that $q_j\ne 2,\forall j$):

$$z^2=2^2p_1^{r_1}\dots p_m^{r_m}q_1^{s_1}\dots q_n^{s_n},$$ from where $r_i,s_j$ are even. So $x'$ and $y$ are squares. Thus, $x$ is two times a square and $y$ is a square.

Answer (score 1):

Just think that a perfect square must have all its prime factors paired up and if $x $ and $y$ are relatively prime, they don't share prime factors.

If you can't figure it out I can walk you through it, but it is a good exercise to understand this proof with the hint I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $z$ is a square, its prime factors come in multiples of two. And given that $x$ and $y$ are relative prime, they don't share any prime factors. i think you can see it from there.